# Script to change root password

Tags: linux, solaris, aix

Dears,

I want script to change root password with a predefined password for Solaris 10,11, AIX, Linux without prompting to enter password.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -e "password\npassword" | passwd
```

Just run this as root.

However, there are some serious security concerns about keeping your password in plain text so be careful.